# Pandas data frame to Json

Tags: json, pandas

I got this panda data frame.

```
{
    'attendeeCount': [3,1,0],
    'attendees': ['x@xx.com,y@yy.com,z@zz.com','k@kk.com',''],
    'partyName': ['party1','party2', 'party3'],
    'partyDate': ['2024-01-15', '2024-02-10', '']
}
```

Need to produce a json that looks like the following json.

```
{
  "parties": [
    {
      "attendeeCount": 3,
      "attendees": [
        "x@xx.com",
        "y@yy.com",
        "z@zz.com"
      ],
      "partyName": "party1",
      "partyDate": "2024-01-15"
    },
    {
      "attendeeCount": 1,
      "attendees": [
        "k@kk.com"
      ],
      "partyName": "party2",
      "partyDate": "2024-02-10"
    },
    {
      "attendeeCount": 0,
      "attendees": [],
      "partyName": "party3",
      "partyDate": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I am hoping not to iterate thru each row to build the json. Any help appreciated. I know, eventually I will get hang of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get something close to what you want by replacing empty strings with `None` and then splitting `attendees` before converting the dataframe to a dict and then JSON:

```
df = df.replace({ '' : None })
df['attendees'] = df['attendees'].str.split(',')
out = json.dumps({ 'parties' : df.to_dict(orient='records') }, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
{
    "parties": [
        {
            "attendeeCount": 3,
            "attendees": [
                "x@xx.com",
                "y@yy.com",
                "z@zz.com"
            ],
            "partyName": "party1",
            "partyDate": "2024-01-15"
        },
        {
            "attendeeCount": 1,
            "attendees": [
                "k@kk.com"
            ],
            "partyName": "party2",
            "partyDate": "2024-02-10"
        },
        {
            "attendeeCount": 0,
            "attendees": null,
            "partyName": "party3",
            "partyDate": null
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case `attendees` for `party3` is `null`, not an empty list. If you want an empty list, you can replace commas in the `attendees` values with space and then split on `None`:

```
df['attendees'] = df['attendees'].str.replace(',', ' ').str.split()
df['partyDate'] = df['partyDate'].replace({ '' : None })
out = json.dumps({ 'parties' : df.to_dict(orient='records') }, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
{
    "parties": [
        {
            "attendeeCount": 3,
            "attendees": [
                "x@xx.com",
                "y@yy.com",
                "z@zz.com"
            ],
            "partyName": "party1",
            "partyDate": "2024-01-15"
        },
        {
            "attendeeCount": 1,
            "attendees": [
                "k@kk.com"
            ],
            "partyName": "party2",
            "partyDate": "2024-02-10"
        },
        {
            "attendeeCount": 0,
            "attendees": [],
            "partyName": "party3",
            "partyDate": null
        }
    ]
}
```